# What kind of pipe should I use for a gutter drain under a driveway?

Tags: pipe, drainage, underground

I need to divert water from a rain gutter. The problem is that I need to run the pipe under a side driveway. What is the best pipe that will hold up with vehicle traffic? How deep does the ditch need to be? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to go cheap and just buy the schedule 30 (20?) stuff they use for drainage at your local box store (Home Depot/Menard's/Lowe's) 10' under the driveway 6" deep. If it somehow doesn't hold up you could dig it up and put in something heavier.

Or you could bury schedule 40 PVC or if you are worried about it or you could use schedule 80 PVC if you are really worried about it.

The difference in price for a 10' length is negligible but I think you will need adapters if the rest of your drainage is regular drain pipe and you want to put standard plumbing or electrical PVC under the driveway.

Good luck with your project!